# Custom DLL in InfoPath form not working on SharePoint

Tags: development, infopath

I created a form in InfoPath 2007 that uses C# code behind. The form basically is a "user friendly" front end for our current Help Desk ticketing software. The form communicates with the Help Desk via web services and works great. Now, here comes the problem:

I wrote a custom class (DLL) in Visual Studio that calls these web services. This was done so we could just reference the class in a form and instantly give that form the ability to communicate with the Help Desk ticketing software. If I create a new InfoPath form, add the library, and debug the form on my computer everything works great. I then publish the form to SharePoint 2013 and activate it without issue. When I open the form from SharePoint tough I get an error message:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Help_Desk', Version=1.0.4875.20920, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=928d96f33fb2151b' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 94ed1d9c-7501-80fe-37be-8816c9714c4c

The custom library is strongly-named and signed. It is located on a network share accessible by everyone. Here are some things I have tried:

- Dragged & Dropped the DLL into the GAC
- Tried setting "Copy to Local" to TRUE and FALSE with no success
- Double checked that the Version and Public Key stated in the error message was the same as the DLL deployed to the SharePoint servers GAC
- Ensured that the DLL was in the Bin/Release folder on my machine before publishing it to SharePoint

The form its self is hard set to "Full Trust" and Browser enabled. My work around has been to copy and paste the actual code from the custom DLL to a "Class" within the form. This works, but is tedious and not a good solution for making the "Help Desk" functionality easily to implement in InfoPath forms.